# iTextSharp - cut last row of table

Tags: .net, vba, itext

I have generated table with while cycle , but last row iTextSharp cut away....Have anybody any ideas how to fix it.... see code below.

```
mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("č.m.", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Hodnota (mm)", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("č.m.", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Hodnota (mm)", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("č.m.", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Hodnota (mm)", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("č.m.", spec_font)))
        mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Hodnota (mm)", spec_font)))

        Dim mesure_array As Double() = dgv_do_array(cislo_merania)
        Dim average_value As Double = create_average(cislo_merania)

        Dim k As Integer = 0
        While k < cislo_merania
            mesure_tale.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(k + 1, spec_font)))
            Dim mesure_cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(mesure_array(k).ToString, spec_font))

            If mesure_array(k) > (average_value + (average_value * percentualna_odchylka)) Then
                mesure_cell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(255, 120, 120) 'Red
                mesure_tale.AddCell(mesure_cell)
            ElseIf mesure_array(k) < (average_value - (average_value * percentualna_odchylka)) Then
                mesure_cell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(120, 170, 255) 'Blue
                mesure_tale.AddCell(mesure_cell)
            Else
                mesure_cell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(175, 255, 120) ' Green
                mesure_tale.AddCell(mesure_cell)
            End If
            k += 1
        End While

        pdfDoc.Add(mesure_tale)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's being cut away? Have you looked at `mesure_tale` in the debugger to see if it contains all the rows. I'm guess that the last expected row isn't being added by your while loop, as Thomas Inzina's suggests below.

Comment: I just looking debug output, and its true, the last row is missing... it means that cycle is bad constructed... ok, i re-debug my cycle and we will see.... THX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `dgv_do_array(cislo_merania)` is returning the highest bound of the array not the actual length of the array.

Change

> While k < cislo_merania

To

> While k <= cislo_merania

Comment: I tried this fix but ends whit err... , so i thing it's only some stting of iTextSharp library...

Comment: iTextSharp only shows complete rows. If you have an error in your column count, the last row isn't complete and it's dropped for that reason. You can avoid this by using the `CompleteRow()` method. If that doesn't work, please check the version of iText you are using. As documented, versions predating iText 5 dropped rows for inexplicable reasons once in a trillion times (edge cases that were hard to fix). This problem has been fixed a long time ago, so please make sure you are using a recent version of iTextSharp.

Comment: Finally, cycle was good constructed. **CompleteRow** function was that i looking for. THX